# How can I create a regex to match the inner-most match or work from right-to-left?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, grunt-usemin

I'm trying to match the strings for image references but am picking up a little too much when there's an expression involved.  In this example http://www.regexr.com/3b3ub, you'll see I'm doing good on the 1st and 3rd matches but I'm getting too much in the 2nd match.  I only want the `'images/md-icons/ic_notifications_24px.svg'` but am actually getting `"{{ vm.actions.length ?` also.

Is there some negation or qualifier I can use to be non-greedy, inner-most match?

Comment: How about using `["'](images\S+.svg)['"]` or `["'](\S+.svg)['"]`. Notice the use of one or more non-whitespace `\S` match?

Comment: @zedfoxus, thanks for the comment.  I can't use your first solution because I don't want to assume `images` will always be in the path.  However, your second solution is simple and works well with one minor addition as noted in @joe-derose's 4th bullet about using `\.svg`.  An additional note about usefulness of your solution is that the match must be in the first group which you did!  Thank you!

Comment: @zedfoxus, If you'll submit `["'](\S+\.svg)['"]` as an answer, I'll choose it as the best approach for my particular problem.

Comment: Sure, I will submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate the information you want by using

```
["'](images\S+.svg)['"]
```

or

```
["'](\S+.svg)['"]
```

The first solution looks at 'images\anything-but-a-non-whitespace.svg' whereas the second solution looks at 'anything-but-a-non-whitespace.svg'.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things going on here:

- As @chris85 pointed out, you want to match the *only* type of closing quote that corresponds to the opening quote. Chris's example was `("|')`, which absolutely works -- but your original of `["']` will work fine as well as long as you frame it in parentheses, `(["'])`, so the `\1` at the end can refer to it.
- You question specifically asked about a "non-greedy" modifier. The regex term is "lazy", and it absolutely exists: `?`. Just put it after the `.*`.
- The asterisk in that `.*` matches zero or more times -- but I don't think you'd ever want to find an example where it was zero-length (which would just be "**.svg**"). It's a matter of personal preference, but I recommend changing it to a `+` (matches one or more times).
- In your example regex, the dot in the characters "**.svg**" is not finding a literal dot, but rather *any* character (so "**xsvg**" would also be a match). You need to escape it with a backslash to make it a literal dot: `\.svg`.

The regex you want is: `(["'])(.*?\.svg)\1`

Here's the link: http://www.regexr.com/3b3uq

**Update**

I see that while I was typing, Chris made some edits that covered the same ground that I was covering. I've upvoted that answer.

Comment: Thank you, what an excellent explanation!  An additional constraint is that my match must be in the first grouping.  @zedfoxus provided a solution that's going to work well for me (with the addition of your escaping the `.svg`.  I missed that, thanks for catching it!

Comment: Good advice about the `.*`.  One of my rules of thumb is **Never use `*` when `+` is what you mean.**  You make the regex do unnecessary work, eliminating possible matches it shouldn't have considered in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You should match the same quotes.

```
("|')(.*.svg)\1
```

http://regexr.com/3b3uh

Currently you say double quote or single quote and again. You want to match whatever type of quote the first one was though.

You probably should actually escape the `.` before the svg so it is the literal and also check for the first `.svg`.

http://regexr.com/3b3uk

```
("|')(.*?\.svg)\1
```

The `\1` is a back-reference, it refers to the first captured group (double quote or single quote). http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: Thanks Chris!  I was saying that in my head but had no idea how to translate it into the regex, very clever!  I'm constrained to ensuring the first grouping includes my match so I can't use the backref technique but will keep that in mind.  Thanks for catching the need to escape the dot before the svg extension, I missed that!

Comment: Okay than how about this, `(:?"(.*?\.svg)"|'(.*?\.svg)')`?

Comment: it's a little too verbose for me but i'm impressed at your regex Ninjutsu :-)